# How to pass additional parameters from the nodejs client to webhook via dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Actually I want to pass some additional parameters such as username, user ID to webhook but I am not able to do this.

I am using detectIntent() method of sessionClient. Following are request:

```
function detectEventIntent(projectId, sessionId, eventName, languageCode) {

  // Imports the Dialogflow library
  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

  // Instantiates a sessison client
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

  // The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

  // The text query request.
  const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: query,
          languageCode: languageCode,
        },
      },
      queryParams:{
         payload: {
            data:{
             username: 'gaurav',
             userId: usr1
            }
         }
     }
  };

  sessionClient
    .detectIntent(request)
    .then(responses => {
      console.log('Detected intent');

      logQueryResult(sessionClient, responses[0].queryResult);
    })

    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });

}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with using `queryParams.payload`? Any errors? Not able to use the values? How are you trying to use the values?

Comment: How does your intent look like? are you using Entity and Parameters?

Answer (score -2):

There are differences in passing some additional parameters such as username, user ID in dialogFlow V1 and dialogFlow V2.
In dialogFlow V1 its relatively hard to  pass additional parameters whereas in dialogFlow V2 one can easily pass user ID, project ID. Just give additional functions in the dialogFlow after

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
```

Just give as:-

```
let projectId = 'Name as you like';
let sessionId = ' As you Like ';
let dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
let config = {
  credentials: {
    private_key: "....Your Key.....",
    client_email: "....Your Service Account mail...."
  }
}
```